# Form submit handler executing before ajaxStop

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I've set some handlers for this whole project to show/hide the loading div.

Some of them are `ajaxStart`, `ajaxStop` (both binded to `$(document)`) and `submit` that is bind to the `forms`.

I can't understand why the `ajaxStop` is executing after the `form.submit` in the sample bellow:

```js
var blobs = [];

var echo = function echo(data, type) {
  var blob = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {
    "type": type
  }));

  blobs.push(blob);

  return blob
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    console.log('form submit');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}).ajaxStart(function() {
  console.log('ajaxStart');
}).ajaxStop(function() {
  console.log('ajaxStop');
});

$('button').click(function() {
  $.get(echo("Sample data", "text/html"), function(data) {
    if (data != '')
      $('#frm').submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frm">
  <button type="button">
    Send
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because `ajaxStop()` is called after the `complete` event fires on all active AJAX requests.

You see the `form submit` in the console because you fire that event in the `success` handler, which occurs *before* `complete`.

Comment: So I should've used `.complete` or `.always`?

Comment: Neither would make a difference. `ajaxStop()` fires after all requests have completed. You can see the order here: https://jsfiddle.net/872dmpxe/

Comment: After running some tests (including yours) I fully understand the sequence and what I had to change. I had to include a class to the form saying that is being submited, so I don't close the loader in the `ajaxStop` that comes after. Thanks.